# How to validate duplicate entries before inserting to database - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed simple application, i have generated checkbox in grid dynamically from database, but my problem is when user select the checkbox and other required field from grid and press submit button, it adds duplicate value, so i want to know how can i check the checkbox value & other field value with database value while submitting data to database.

following code i use to generate all selected items and then save too db

```
    foreach ($this->addattendee->results as $key=>$value)
{
//print_r($value);
$id = $this->Attendee_model->save($value);
}
```

i am using codeigniter....can any one give the idea with sample code plz

```
 {
    $person = $this->Person_model->get_by_id($id)->row();
    $this->form_data->id = $person->tab_classid;
    $this->form_data->classtitle = $person->tab_classtitle;
    $this->form_data->classdate = $person->tab_classtime;
    $this->form_data->createddate = $person->tab_crtdate;
    $this->form_data->peremail = $person->tab_pemail;
    $this->form_data->duration = $person->tab_classduration;

    //Show User Grid - Attendee>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    $uri_segment = 0;
    $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);
    $users = $this->User_model->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();
    // generate pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('person/index/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->User_model->count_all();
    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    // generate table data
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
    $this->table->set_heading('Check', 'User Id','User Name', 'Email', 'Language');
    $i = 0 + $offset;
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $checkarray=array('name'=>'chkclsid[]','id'=>'chkclsid','value'=>$user->user_id);
        $this->table->add_row(form_checkbox($checkarray), $user->user_id, $user->user_name, $user->user_email,$user->user_language
        /*,anchor('person/view/'.$user->user_id,'view',array('class'=>'view')).' '.
        anchor('person/update/'.$user->user_id,'update',array('class'=>'update')).' '.
        anchor('person/showattendee/'.$user->user_id,'Attendee',array('class'=>'attendee')).' '.
        anchor('person/delete/'.$user->user_id,'delete',array('class'=>'delete','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this person?')"))*/ );
    }
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
```

//end grid code

```
    // load view
    // set common properties
    $data['title'] = 'Assign Attendees';
    $msg = '';
    $data['message'] = $msg;
    $data['action'] = site_url('person/CreateAttendees');
    //$data['value'] = "sssssssssssssssssss";
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = "<p>Welcome:"." ".$session_data['username']. " | " . anchor('home/logout', 'Logout')." | ". "Userid :"." ".$session_data['id']; "</p>";
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/','Back to list of Classes',array('class'=>'back'));
    $this->load->view('common/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('adminmenu');
    $this->load->view('addattendee_v', $data);

}
```

Comment: I think we should be talking about the generated HTML first, since the submit button posts data from the browser interface to the server(PHP). So, kindly show us your generated HTML code.

Comment: The code is way to messy... where do you validate your user input?

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite messy but I have solved a similar issue in my application I think, I am not sure if its the best way, but it works.

```
function save_vote($vote,$show_id, $stats){
    // Check if new vote
    $this->db->from('show_ratings')
            ->where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->where('show_id', $show_id);
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    $user_vote = $rs->row_array();
            // Here we are check if that entry exists
    if ($rs->num_rows() == '0' ){
        // Its a new vote so insert data

        $this->db->insert('show_ratings', $rate);

    }else{
        // Its a not new vote, so we update the DB. I also added a UNIQUE KEY to my database for the user_id and show_id fields in the show_ratings table. So There is that extra protection.
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO `show_ratings`  (`user_id`,`show_id`,`score`) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `score`=?;', array($user_id, $show_id, $vote, $vote));
        return $update;
    }
}
```

I hope this code snippet gives you some idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i have same trouble with you.
and this is what i did.

```
<?php
public function set_news(){
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $query = $this->db->query("select slug from news where slug like '%$slug%'");
        if($query->num_rows()>=1){
            $jum = $query->num_rows() + 1;
            $slug = $slug.'-'.$jum;
        }

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('news', $data);        
    }
?>
```

then it works.